# Does SQL Mail 2000 work with Outlook 2003?

Tags: sql-server

Knowledge Base article [#281293](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281293/) says:

> The SQL Mail feature of SQL Server
>   2000 does not work if Microsoft
>   Outlook 2000 is not installed on the
>   server that functions as the mail
>   client.

We don't have a copy of Outlook 2000 laying around, but we do have 2003.  Will SQL Mail work with Outlook 2003 as its MAPI provider instead of Outlook 2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we currently have that setup in production.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Per Microsoft

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/897349

> In Microsoft SQL Server 2000, you can
>   configure SQL Mail or SQL Agent Mail
>   to use an Internet mail protocol such
>   as Simple Mail Transfer Protocol
>   (SMTP) or Post Office Protocol 3
>   (POP3). However, Microsoft Office
>   Outlook 2003 must be running on the
>   computer that is running SQL Server
>   for you to send and receive e-mail
>   messages. This article describes how
>   to configure SQL Mail to use an
>   Internet mail server by using Outlook
>   2003.